# Android - Kotlin - sorting data from json assets file

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting

I'm new to Kotlin (and even programming), and I've been trying to read a local json file in assets. This works and I can render the results in a recyclerview. But now I want to sort the results, based on the name:

Model:

```
data class Station(
    val name: String?,
    val country: String?,
    val icon: String?,
    val synonym: String?,
    val backend: Backend,
    val geocoordinates: GeoCoordinates,
    val enabled: Enabled,
)

data class Backend(val bene: String?, val sabin: String?)
data class GeoCoordinates(val longitude: Double?, val latitude: Double?)
data class Enabled(val booking: Boolean?, val schedule: Boolean?, val stationboard: Boolean?)
data class StationsModelClass(val stations: ArrayList<Station>)
```

In Mainactivity, I'm loading the json file via this:

```
try {
    val jsonString = readJsonFile(this, "stations.json") // retrieve data from json file
    val station = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, StationsModelClass::class.java) // convert data from json file to string
    //val sortedStation = station.sortedWith(compareBy { it.name})
    binding.stationList.adapter = StationItemAdapter(station.stations) // set adapter instance equals to the recyclerView to inflate the items from our model

} catch (e: JSONException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I've been trying to sort the json with the uncommented line, but an error is thrown. Any help would be much appreciated. The next step would be to link a SearchView to filter the json, where the query matches the name AND synonym.

Comment: "an error is thrown" is the equivalent of "my car doesn't work". Could you at least tell us what the error is? Btw, you might want to try and replace the `sortedWith(...)` with `sortedBy { it.year }`.

Comment: Hi Alex, the error, when using sortedWith or sortedBy is : Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch.

Comment: that makes sense, there is no `year` property in the `Station` class.

Comment: My mistake, I took over your example. The error is the same when I put it.name.